# How to refer to a field that starts with a digit in dust.js?

Tags: javascript, dust.js

I've got a JSON structure like this and want to refer to the 64x64 image in a dust template. This doesn't work because of the 64x64.

```
   "images": [
        {
            "dateLastUpdated": "2014-02-24T23:00:00Z",
            "links": {
                "1024x1024": "http://imghost/some.JPG",
                "147x147": "http://imghost/some.JPG",
                "358x358": "http://imghost/some.JPG",
                "498x498": "http://imghost/some.JPG",
                "64x64": "http://imghost/some.JPG",
                "726x726": "http://imghost/some.JPG"
            },
            "status": "OK"
        }
    ],
```

This is the dust.js template

```
{#users}
<tr>
  <td><img class="thumb" src="{.images[0].links['64x64']}"/></td>
  <td>{.title}</td>
</tr>
{/users}
```

I've tried

```
{.images[0].links.64x64}
{.images[0].links['64x64']}
{.images[0].links.'64x64'}
{'.images[0].links.64x64'}
```

How do I do this?

**Update 1**

I've found a workaround which solves this specific problem but not the general one. If I would want to refer to different sizes in the loop I would have the same problem again.

```
{#users $size="64x64"}
<tr>
  <td><img class="thumb" src="{.images[0].links[$size]}"/></td>
  <td>{.title}</td>
</tr>
{/users}
```

**Update 2**

Should have mentioned the dust.js template in the question :)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
var data =  {"images": [
    {
        "dateLastUpdated": "2014-02-24T23:00:00Z",
        "links": {
            "1024x1024": "http://imghost/some.JPG",
            "147x147": "http://imghost/some.JPG",
            "358x358": "http://imghost/some.JPG",
            "498x498": "http://imghost/some.JPG",
            "64x64": "http://imghost/some.JPG",
            "726x726": "http://imghost/some.JPG"
        },
        "status": "OK"
    }
]};
console.log(data.images[0].links['64x64']);
```

Comment: yeah, that works but I'm looking for variable expansion in dust specifically. :)

Comment: I don't anything about dust, what you asked was about simply javascript and json. so i explained it.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention the dust template in the question. Duh. Will update this. thx

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. The Dust grammar does not allow for keys to start with a number. If you have the ability to modify your JSON before the template is rendered, you could prefix all of those keys with `_` or `img`, then use `{_1024x1024}` or `{img1024x1024}` in your Dust template.

Comment: And there is no way to reference the key via array syntax, e.g. links['64']?